# how to send string as parameter in batch file function?

Tags: function, parameters, batch-file, special-characters, pipe

hello I am making web page searching program with windows batch file

before searching it, I need to save html code to variable and regex.

I am on windows xp sp3

I wonder how can I send special character mixed string as function parameter

my code is here

```
cd curl-7.25

for /f "tokens=*" %%R IN ('curl.exe -G --max-redirs 3 http://www.google.com?') DO call:MyFunc %%R

pause

:MyFunc
echo %~1
goto:eof
```

the problem is on "call:MyFunc %%R"

the html code includes many '<' and '>' (brackets)

and this interpreted as piping.

which I am trying to avoid.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't escape the content of %%R, as you receive it from curl.
But you can handle it with delayed expansion.

```
cd curl-7.25
set "curlCmd=curl.exe -G --max-redirs 3 http://www.google.com?"

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%R IN ('!curlCmd!') DO (
  set "line=%%R"
  call :MyFunc line
)
pause
exit /b

:MyFunc
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !%~1!
rem ** Or you can use directly echo !line!
endlocal
exit /b
```

I first disable delayed expansion, else you get problems with exclamation marks and/or carets.
And then I call `:MyFunc` with the variable name not the content, as call would modify the content.

And to access the content I enable the delayed expansion, as delayed expansion never modify or interfere with the content of a variable.